# cumulative days passed since reoccurring event by group

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to calculate the cumulative days passed since `event==1`. Is it possible to do this in R using `data.table`?

Desired outcome:

```
    id       date event passed
 1:  A 2000-01-13     1      0
 2:  A 2000-01-18     0      5
 3:  A 2000-01-25     0     12
 4:  A 2000-01-31     1      0
 5:  B 2012-10-10     1      0
 6:  B 2012-10-11     0      1
 7:  B 2012-10-14     1      0
 8:  B 2012-10-15     0      1
 9:  C 2005-07-25     1      0
10:  C 2005-07-31     0      6

df <- data.table(
  id    = c("A", "A", "A", "A", 
            "B", "B", "B", "B", 
            "C", "C"), 
  date  = c("2000-01-13", "2000-01-18", "2000-01-25", "2000-01-31", # A
            "2012-10-10", "2012-10-11", "2012-10-14", "2012-10-15", # B
            "2005-07-25", "2005-07-31"),                            # C
  event = c(1, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 1, 0,
            1, 0)
    )
```

**edit (12/12/17): tried with @Psidom's solution.**

Solution requires `id` and `date` to be sorted, which isn't a problem. Noticed however that line 6: counted a day although this should be 0 given no event for that group had yet occurred.

```
df2 <- df[sample(nrow(df)),]
df2 = df2[order(id, date)]
df2[, days_from_start := cumsum(c(0, diff(as.Date(date)))), by = .(id, cumsum(event))]

    id       date event days_from_start
 1:  A 2000-01-13     1               0
 2:  A 2000-01-18     0               5
 3:  A 2000-01-25     0              12
 4:  A 2000-01-31     0              18
 5:  B 2012-10-10     0               0
 6:  B 2012-10-11     0               1
 7:  B 2012-10-14     1               0
 8:  B 2012-10-15     0               1
 9:  C 2005-07-25     1               0
10:  C 2005-07-31     0               6
```

Answer (score 4):

If `event` column contains only `0` and `1`, you can create a group variable by doing `cumsum(event)` which creates a new group whenever `event` is `1`; Then group by this new variable, calculate the cumulative days:

```
df[, days_from_start := cumsum(c(0, diff(as.Date(date)))), by = cumsum(event)]
#                                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
df
#    id       date event days_from_start
# 1:  A 2000-01-13     1               0
# 2:  A 2000-01-18     0               5
# 3:  A 2000-01-25     0              12
# 4:  A 2000-01-31     1               0
# 5:  B 2012-10-10     1               0
# 6:  B 2012-10-11     0               1
# 7:  B 2012-10-14     1               0
# 8:  B 2012-10-15     0               1
# 9:  C 2005-07-25     1               0
#10:  C 2005-07-31     0               6
```

Comment: is there a way to subset it also my group (id). Turns out that the cumulative numbers will continue to count across groups.

Comment: You can add id to the group variable. ‘by = .(id, cumsum(event))’

Comment: Seems like you could do something like `date - first(date)` instead of cumsum. Of course the OP should just overwrite the date with a Date/IDate-class column instead of parsing it temporarily by group. Also, you want NAs prior to the first event per id, I guess (or zero, says the OP).